# Rewrite img and link paths with htaccess and serve the file from rewritten path?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a static mockup page, which I want to "customize" by switching a variable used in image-src and link-href attributes.

Paths will look like this:

```
<img src="/some/where/VARIABLE/img/1.jpg" alt="" />
<link rel="some" href="/some/where/VARIABLE/stuff/foo.bar" />
```

I'm setting a cookie with the VARIABLE value on the preceding page and now want to modfiy the paths accordingly by replacing VARIABLE with the cookie value.

I'm a htaccess newbie. This is what I have (doesn't work):

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # get cookie value cookie
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} client=([^;]*)
    # rewrite/redirect to correct file
    RewriteRule  ^/VARIABLE/(.+)$  /%1/$1 [L]   
 </IfModule>
```

So I thought my first line gets the cookie value and stores this in %1. And on the second line I'm filtering VARIABLE, replace it with the cookie value and whatever comes after VARIABLE in $1.

Thanks for sheeding some light on what I'm doing, doing wrong and if I can do this at all using htaccess.

**EDIT:**
I'm sort of halfway through, but it's still not working... Mabye someone can apply the finishing touches:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # check for client cookie   
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:^|;\s*)client=([^;]*)
    # check if an image was requested   
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$
    # exclude these folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !some/members/logos  

    # grab everything before the variable folder and everything afterwards
    # replace this with first bracket/cookie_value/second bracket
    RewriteRule (^.+)/VARIABLE/(.+)$ $1/%1/$2 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Still can't get it to work, but I think this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** (after much meddling...)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # exclude these folders
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/some/members/logos  
   # check for client cookie        
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} client=([^;]*) [NC]       
   # replace variable with cookie value
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/variabel/(.+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ $1/%1/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The tricky part, which took forever to solve is to make sure your cookie has a trailing semi-colon... I had my cookie set like this:

```
   document.cookie = "client=value"
```

which did not work at all. After changing to this:

```
   document.cookie = "client="+escape("value")+";"
```

it worked. Semi-colon... Maybe this save somebody half a day of searching :-)